# Flutter Provider nested navigation

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a problem with provider and navigation.

I have a `HomeScreen` with a list of objects. When you click on one object I navigate to a `DetailScreen` with tab navigation. This `DetailScreen` is wrapped with a ChangenotifierProvider which provides a `ViewModel`

Now, when I navigate to another screen with `Navigator.of(context).push(EditScreen)` I can't access the `ViewModel` within the `EditScreen`
The following error is thrown

```
════════ Exception caught by gesture ═══════════════════════════════════════════
The following ProviderNotFoundException was thrown while handling a gesture:
Error: Could not find the correct Provider<ViewModel> above this EditScreen Widget
```

This is a simple overview of what I try to achieve

```
Home Screen
 - Detail Screen (wrapped with ChangeNotifierProvider)
   - Edit Screen
     - access provider from here
```

I know what the problem is. I'm pushing a new screen on the stack and the change notifier is not available anymore.
I thought about creating a Detail Repository on top of my App which holds all of the ViewModels for the DetailView.

I know I could wrap the ChangeNotifier around my MaterialApp, but I don't want that, or can't do it because I don't know which Detail-ViewModel I need. I want a ViewModel for every item in the list

I really don't know what's the best way to solve this. Thanks everyone for the help

Here is a quick example app:

[This is a picture of the image tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wkY6.png)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
            child: RaisedButton(
      child: Text("DetailView"),
      onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => ChangeNotifierProvider(
              create: (_) => ViewModel(), child: DetailScreen()))),
    )));
  }
}

class DetailScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const DetailScreen({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
      child: RaisedButton(
        child: Text("EditScreen"),
        onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context)
            .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => EditScreen())),
      ),
    ));
  }
}

class EditScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const EditScreen({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
            child: Text("Print"),
            onPressed: () =>
                Provider.of<ViewModel>(context, listen: false).printNumber()),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ViewModel extends ChangeNotifier {
  printNumber() {
    print(2);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 27):

To be able to access providers accross navigations, you need to provide it before MaterialApp as follows

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (_) => ViewModel(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        home: MyHomePage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
            child: RaisedButton(
      child: Text("DetailView"),
      onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).push(
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => DetailScreen(),
        ),
      ),
    )));
  }
}

class DetailScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const DetailScreen({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
      child: RaisedButton(
        child: Text("EditScreen"),
        onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context)
            .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => EditScreen())),
      ),
    ));
  }
}

class EditScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const EditScreen({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
            child: Text("Print"),
            onPressed: () =>
                Provider.of<ViewModel>(context, listen: false).printNumber()),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ViewModel extends ChangeNotifier {
  printNumber() {
    print(2);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know that this works, but I can't do that because I don't only have one ViewModel but one ViewModel for every DetailScreen.

Comment: I think then, you need to provide each ViewModel using multi provider, If they are all different classes

Comment: I don't understand. I need to inialise the View models with data from the list. so I cant provide them 'above' my main app

Comment: If you are passing instance of viewmodel to each detail page on list click, why bother using provider, just pass the instance directly as parameters to widgets, why not do that?

Comment: it's explained in my original question. viewmodel is maybe the wrong word, let's say bloc instead. I want to use in the edit view that I push. I hope this is understandable.
I don't really understand what you mean with passing into the detail page? so I should pass it into the detail page and in every widget that I use in that page? plus the edit screen?

Comment: Checkout this tutorial, this might be helpful in your case
https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-architecture-provider-implementation-guide-d33133a9a4e8

Comment: Also, to answer your question, check out this issue, reply from the provider creator
https://github.com/rrousselGit/provider/issues/128

Comment: thanks so much for your help. I know this tutorial, but it doesn't help in my case, same problem if I want to do it the way I mentioned in my question.

And Remi's answer just mentioned that I need to include the provider in my route, but not how it is done. that is actually my question :/ 

I know I could design my app a little bit differentely but every other way doesn't feel natural to me, therefore my question

Comment: Did you find an answer to this question @JosefWilhelm?

Comment: To be able to access providers accross navigations, you need to provide it before MaterialApp as follows

Comment: I have same problem with @JosefWilhelm. Put provider/multi provider before MaterialApp is not what we want, even though it will works.

Comment: try new [riverpod](https://pub.dev/packages/riverpod) state management from the same developer, complete rewrite of provider

Answer (score 21):

A bit late to the party, but I think this is the answer the question was looking for:

(Basically passing the ViewModel down to the next Navigator page.)

```
class DetailScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const DetailScreen({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final viewModel = Provider.of<ViewModel>(context); // Get current ViewModel
    return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
      child: RaisedButton(
        child: Text("EditScreen"),
        onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).push(
          // Pass ViewModel down to EditScreen
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
            return ChangeNotifierProvider.value(value: viewModel, child: EditScreen());
          }),
        ),
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

Comment: This answer is more a proper solution than the others. The provider above MaterialApp means the provider will always be "alive" consuming resources. That's not what you usually want. Following this answer, for those pushing a named route, you can pass the provider as an argument and call `ChangeNotifierProvider<SomeProvider>.value()` in your destination screen. Not nice the need to pass it as an argument but I haven't found any other way that looks more proper than this solution.

Comment: what if you want to pass multiple providers to the EditScreen ?

Comment: You can wrap them in a `MultiProvider`. See https://pub.dev/documentation/provider/latest/provider/MultiProvider-class.html

Answer (score 4):

I am a bit late but I found a solution on how to keep the value of a `Provider` alive after a `Navigator.push()` without having to put the `Provider` above the `MaterialApp`.

To do so, I have used the library [`custom_navigator`](https://pub.dev/packages/custom_navigator). It allows you to create a `Navigator` wherever you want in the tree.

You will have to create 2 different `GlobalKey<NavigatorState>` that you will give to the `MaterialApp` and `CustomNavigator` widgets. These keys will allow you to control what Navigator you want to use.

Here is a small snippet to illustrate how to do

```dart
class App extends StatelessWidget {

   GlobalKey<NavigatorState> _mainNavigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>(); // You need to create this key for the MaterialApp too

   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return MaterialApp(
         navigatorKey: _mainNavigatorKey;  // Give the main key to the MaterialApp
         home: Provider<bool>.value(
            value: myProviderFunction(),
            child: Home(),
         ),
      );
   }

}

class Home extends StatelessWidget {

   GlobalKey<NavigatorState> _navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>(); // You need to create this key to control what navigator you want to use

   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {

      final bool myBool = Provider.of<bool>(context);

      return CustomNavigator (
         // CustomNavigator is from the library 'custom_navigator'
         navigatorKey: _navigatorKey,  // Give the second key to your CustomNavigator
         pageRoute: PageRoutes.materialPageRoute,
         home: Scaffold(
            body: FlatButton(
               child: Text('Push'),
               onPressed: () {
                  _navigatorKey.currentState.push(  // <- Where the magic happens
                     MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => SecondHome(),
                     ),
                  },
               ),
            ),
         ),
      );   
   }
}

class SecondHome extends StatelessWidget {

   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {

      final bool myBool = Provider.of<bool>(context);

      return Scaffold(
         body: FlatButton(
            child: Text('Pop'),
            onPressed: () {
               Novigator.pop(context);
            },
         ),
      );
   }

}
```

Here you can read the value `myBool` from the `Provider` in the `Home` widget but also ine the `SecondHome` widget even after a `Navigator.push()`.

However, the Android `back` button will trigger a `Navigator.pop()` from the Navigator of the `MaterialApp`. If you want to use the `CustomNavigator`'s one, you can do this:

```dart
// In the Home Widget insert this
   ...
   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return WillPopScope(
         onWillPop: () async {
            if (_navigatorKey.currentState.canPop()) {
               _navigatorKey.currentState.pop();  // Use the custom navigator when available
               return false;  // Don't pop the main navigator
            } else {
               return true;  // There is nothing to pop in the custom navigator anymore, use the main one
            }
         },
         child: CustomNavigator(...),
      );
   }
   ...
```