# Flutter_bloc: Is there a cleaner way to access the state of a flutter Cubit than a redundant if/else statement?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using [flutter_bloc](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc) and have created a sessionState that gets triggered when a user has successfully authenticated and the state saves the user object (`did`).
I use a Cubit to change the state which then results in showing different screens in the ui. But whenever I want to access the `did` object of the Verified sessionState which holds the user information, I have to create an if else statement in every file to check if the sessionState is `Verified` and if that is true I can access the did object with `state.did`.
I would be interested to know if it's possible to provide this `did` object to all underlying widgets without passing it down manually every widget.
I would like to be able to just access the did object from the context so that I can access it everywhere below where it is provided.
My SessionState:

```
abstract class SessionState {}

class UnkownSessionState extends SessionState {}

class Unverified extends SessionState {}

class Verified extends SessionState {
  Verified({required this.did});

  final Did did;
}
```

The `SessionCubit` launches states that I use to define the global state of the app and show different screens as a result.

```
class SessionCubit extends Cubit<SessionState> {
  SessionCubit(this.commonBackendRepo) : super(UnkownSessionState()) {
    attemptGettingDid();
  }

  final CommonBackendRepo commonBackendRepo;
  final SecureStorage secureStorage = SecureStorage();

  Future<void> attemptGettingDid() async {
    try {
        //more logic
        emit(Unverified());
    } catch (e) {
      emit(Unverified());
    }
  }

  void showUnverified() => emit(Unverified());
  void showSession(Did did) {
    emit(Verified(did: did));
  }
}
```

This is how I currently access the `did` object in every file:

```
BlocBuilder<SessionCubit, SessionState>(builder: (context, state) {
  if (state is Verified) {
    return CustomScrollView(
      slivers: <Widget>[
        SliverAppBar(
          elevation: 0.0,
          backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor,
          title: Text(
            state.did.username,
            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline5,
          ),
        ),
        SliverToBoxAdapter(
            child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
          child: CredentialDetailsView(),
        ))
      ],
    );
  } else {
    return const Text("Unverified");
  }
});
```

**Edit:**
That's how I would imagine the optimal solution to my scenario:

1. Create if/else to check if state is verfied in one parent widget.
2. If state is verfied create a Provider as a child with the 'did' Object so that the children of this Provider don't have to access the SessionState but can just access the provided `did` object.

**Response to Robert Sandberg's answer**
I also have an `AppNavigator` that either start the `authNavigator` or `sessionNavigator`. So the `sessionNavigator` is the parent widget of all widgets that get shown only when the state is `Verified`. So I think this would be a great place to wrap the sessionNavigator with the `Provider.value`, as you explained it.
I wrapped my SessionNavigator with the `Provider.value` widget and provided the state object:

```
class AppNavigator extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder<SessionCubit, SessionState>(
      builder: (context, state) {
        return Navigator(
          pages: [
            if (state is UnkownSessionState)
              MaterialPage(child: StartupScreen()),
            //show auth flow
            if (state is Unverified)
              MaterialPage(
                  child: BlocProvider(
                create: (context) => AuthCubit(context.read<SessionCubit()),
                child: AuthNavigator(),
              )),
            //show session flow
            if (state is Verified)
              MaterialPage(
                  child: Provider.value(
                // here I can access the state.did object
                value: state,
                child: SessionNavigator(),
              ))
          ],
          onPopPage: (route, result) => route.didPop(result),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

For testing I tried to watch the provided value inside of my Home screen which is a child of the SessionNavigator:

```
...
class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //
    final sessionState = context.watch<SessionState>();
    return CustomScrollView(
      slivers: <Widget>[
        SliverAppBar(
          floating: true,
          expandedHeight: 60.0,
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
              title: Text(
                // I can't access state.did because value is of type SessionState
                sessionState.did,
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6,
              ),
              titlePadding:
                  const EdgeInsetsDirectional.only(start: 20, bottom: 16)),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

But because the type of my value is `SessionState` I can't access the did object of the underlying Verified state. I though about providing the state.did object but I don't know how I would watch for that type.
I also got the error that my home screen couldn't find the Provider in the build context. Could that happen because my Home screen has a `Navigator` as parent?
This is a visualization of my app architecture:
[image]

Comment: Let me know if you want me to translate my answer to  your specific classes. I wrote it a bit general for the coming audiences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use this pattern sometimes, and it sounds like my solution very much fits your imagined optimal solution :)

In a parent:

```
BlocBuilder<MyBloc, MyBlocState>(
          builder: (context, state) {
            return state.when(
              stateA: () => SomeWidgetA(),
              stateB: () => SomeWidgetB(),
              stateC: (myValue) {
                return Provider.value(
                  value: myValue,
                  child: SomeWidgetC(),
                );
              }),
           }
          )
```

... and then in `SomeWidgetC()` and all it's children I do the following to get hold of `myValue` (where it is of type `MyValueType`)

```
final myValue = context.watch<MyValueType>();
```

If you want, you could also use regular [InheritedWidget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/InheritedWidget-class.html) instead of using the [Provider package](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) but you get a lot of nifty features with Provider.

**EDIT**
Response to your further questions.

In your case, if you provide the entire state as you do in `AppNavigator`, then you should look for `Verified` state in SessionNavigator as such:

```
final sessionState = context.watch<Verified>();
```

Or, if you only need the Did object, then just provide that, so in AppNavigator:

```
if (state is Verified)
  MaterialPage(
    child: Provider.value(
             value: state.did,
             child: SessionNavigator(),
           ))
```

And then in SessionNavigator:

```
final did = context.watch<Did>();
```

**Edit 3:**
It might be that your problems arises with nested Navigators. Have a look at this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59576495/flutter-provider-nested-navigation) for some guidance.

If you continue struggle, I suggest that you open new SO questions for the specific problems, as this is starting to get a bit wide :) I think that the original question is answered, even though you haven't reached a final solution.

Comment: That looks promising. I just tried it out but I encountered two obsticles which in described in depth in my question (See the lowest **Edit** reference in my question). If you have any further questions feel free to ask me again.

Comment: Watching the Verified state worked for me. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like `(state as Verified).did.username`, but I would still recommend using the if/else pattern since you ensure that you are using the correct state.

In my personal projects, I use the Freezed package (https://pub.dev/packages/freezed) for such cases since there are some useful methods to cover this. For instance, by using freezed, your issue could be resolved as:

```
return state.maybeWhen(
  verified: (did) => CustomScrollView(...),
  orElse: () => const Text("Unverified"),
)
```