# How to avoid boilerplate code in Flutter when changing routes and keeping the providers?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have already solved this problem, but I want to clean the code so it's easier to maintain.

The problem was: When using data that comes from `Provider<T>`, how can I make the providers and their data available in the next view when `Navigator.of(context).push`?

I solved it with this code:

```dart
await Navigator.of(context).push(
  MaterialPageRoute(
    builder: (_) {
      return MultiProvider(
        providers: [
          Provider<User>.value(value: context.read<User>()),
          Provider<Computer>.value(value: context.read<Computer>()),
        ],
        builder: (_, __) => const TheNextScreen(),
      );
    },
    fullscreenDialog: true,
  ),
);
```

This works properly, but I'm concerned about a few points:

- Is this a good design pattern? Or does it look like an anti-pattern? Is there a better way to do it?
- If I type `context` instead of `_`, I'd end up overwriting the original `context` variable and use a `context` that does not have the providers, therefore increasing the risk of errors in the future (e.g. by calling `.read` on the incorrect `context`).
- I saw some other questions and some people used `ChangeNotifierProvider` instead ([Flutter Provider nested navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59576495/flutter-provider-nested-navigation)). This seems like an OK solution and I know how to use `ChangeNotifierProvider`, but as far as I know it doesn't allow a clean way to pass an array of providers, so `MultiProvider` was my choice.

If there's any way to improve this code design (for example, related to the above concerns), that'd be a helpful answer.

Answer (score 2):

Author of Provider here

This problem arises only when you're trying to scope providers (aka having a provider only available for one screen).

A much simpler solution is to not scope the provider at all. Place your providers above `MaterialApp`:

```dart
MultiProvider(
  providers: [...],
  child: MaterialApp(...),
)
```

This way, you won't need to add those providers again when using Navigator.push, since the new route would already have access to them.