# Could not find the correct Provider<CartItemCounter> above this HomeScreen Widget

Tags: flutter, provider

I keep on getting this problem:

Unhandled Exception: Error: Could not find the correct Provider above this HomeScreen Widget

Since I am trying to implement Cart Item Counter, there is this bug.

Here is my code:

Main.dart

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (c) => CartItemCounter()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (c) => TotalAmount()),
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        title: 'Users App',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        home: const MySplashScreen(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Below is my App Bar,  This is where i send users to Cart:

```
class MyAppBar extends StatefulWidget with PreferredSizeWidget {
  final PreferredSizeWidget? bottom;
  final String? sellerUID;

  MyAppBar({this.bottom, this.sellerUID});

  @override
  _MyAppBarState createState() => _MyAppBarState();

  @override
  Size get preferredSize => bottom == null
      ? Size(56, AppBar().preferredSize.height)
      : Size(56, 80 + AppBar().preferredSize.height);
}

class _MyAppBarState extends State<MyAppBar> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AppBar(
      flexibleSpace: Container(
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
          colors: [
            Colors.cyan,
            Colors.amber,
          ],
          begin: FractionalOffset(0.0, 0.0),
          end: FractionalOffset(1.0, 0.0),
          stops: [0.0, 1.0],
          tileMode: TileMode.clamp,
        )),
      ),
      leading: IconButton(
        icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.pop(context);
        },
      ),
      title: const Text(
        "iFood",
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 45, fontFamily: "Signatra"),
      ),
      centerTitle: true,
      automaticallyImplyLeading: true,
      actions: [
        Stack(
          children: [
            IconButton(
              icon: const Icon(
                Icons.shopping_cart,
                color: Colors.cyan,
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                //send user to cart screen
                Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (c) =>
                            CartScreen(sellerUID: widget.sellerUID)));
              },
            ),
            Positioned(
              child: Stack(
                children: [
                  const Icon(
                    Icons.brightness_1,
                    size: 20.0,
                    color: Colors.green,
                  ),
                  Positioned(
                    top: 3,
                    right: 4,
                    child: Center(
                      child: Consumer<CartItemCounter>(
                        builder: (context, counter, c) {
                          return Text(
                            counter.count.toString(),
                            style: const TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white, fontSize: 12),
                          );
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Following is My Cart Screen:

I want to display cart items with quantity number

```
class CartScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final String? sellerUID;

  CartScreen({this.sellerUID});

  @override
  _CartScreenState createState() => _CartScreenState();
}

class _CartScreenState extends State<CartScreen> {
  List<int>? separateItemQuantityList;
  num totalAmount = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    totalAmount = 0;
    Provider.of<TotalAmount>(context, listen: false).displayTotalAmount(0);

    separateItemQuantityList = separateItemQuantities();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        flexibleSpace: Container(
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              gradient: LinearGradient(
            colors: [
              Colors.cyan,
              Colors.amber,
            ],
            begin: FractionalOffset(0.0, 0.0),
            end: FractionalOffset(1.0, 0.0),
            stops: [0.0, 1.0],
            tileMode: TileMode.clamp,
          )),
        ),
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: const Icon(Icons.clear_all),
          onPressed: () {
            clearCartNow(context);
          },
        ),
        title: const Text(
          "iFood",
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 45, fontFamily: "Signatra"),
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
        automaticallyImplyLeading: true,
        actions: [
          Stack(
            children: [
              IconButton(
                icon: const Icon(
                  Icons.shopping_cart,
                  color: Colors.cyan,
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  print("clicked");
                },
              ),
              Positioned(
                child: Stack(
                  children: [
                    const Icon(
                      Icons.brightness_1,
                      size: 20.0,
                      color: Colors.green,
                    ),
                    Positioned(
                      top: 3,
                      right: 4,
                      child: Center(
                        child: Consumer<CartItemCounter>(
                          builder: (context, counter, c) {
                            return Text(
                              counter.count.toString(),
                              style: const TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white, fontSize: 12),
                            );
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
      floatingActionButton: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
        children: [
          const SizedBox(
            width: 10,
          ),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
            child: FloatingActionButton.extended(
              label: const Text(
                "Clear Cart",
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
              ),
              backgroundColor: Colors.cyan,
              icon: const Icon(Icons.clear_all),
              onPressed: () {
                clearCartNow(context);

                Navigator.push(context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (c) => const MySplashScreen()));

                Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "Cart has been cleared.");
              },
            ),
          ),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
            child: FloatingActionButton.extended(
              label: const Text(
                "Check Out",
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
              ),
              backgroundColor: Colors.cyan,
              icon: const Icon(Icons.navigate_next),
              onPressed: () {
                // Navigator.push(
                //   context,
                //   MaterialPageRoute(
                //     builder: (c) => AddressScreen(
                //       totalAmount: totalAmount.toDouble(),
                //       sellerUID: widget.sellerUID,
                //     ),
                //   ),
                // );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: [
          //overall total amount
          SliverPersistentHeader(
              pinned: true, delegate: TextWidgetHeader(title: "My Cart List")),

          SliverToBoxAdapter(
            child: Consumer2<TotalAmount, CartItemCounter>(
                builder: (context, amountProvider, cartProvider, c) {
              return Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                child: Center(
                  child: cartProvider.count == 0
                      ? Container()
                      : Text(
                          "Total Price: " + amountProvider.tAmount.toString(),
                          style: const TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.black,
                            fontSize: 18,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                          ),
                        ),
                ),
              );
            }),
          ),

          //display cart items with quantity number
          StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
            stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                .collection("items")
                .where("itemID", whereIn: separateItemIDs())
                .orderBy("publishedDate", descending: true)
                .snapshots(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              return !snapshot.hasData
                  ? SliverToBoxAdapter(
                      child: Center(
                        child: circularProgress(),
                      ),
                    )
                  : snapshot.data!.docs.length == 0
                      ? //startBuildingCart()
                      Container()
                      : SliverList(
                          delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                            (context, index) {
                              Items model = Items.fromJson(
                                snapshot.data!.docs[index].data()!
                                    as Map<String, dynamic>,
                              );

                              if (index == 0) {
                                totalAmount = 0;
                                totalAmount = totalAmount +
                                    (model.price! *
                                        separateItemQuantityList![index]);
                              } else {
                                totalAmount = totalAmount +
                                    (model.price! *
                                        separateItemQuantityList![index]);
                              }

                              if (snapshot.data!.docs.length - 1 == index) {
                                WidgetsBinding.instance
                                    .addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
                                  Provider.of<TotalAmount>(context,
                                          listen: false)
                                      .displayTotalAmount(
                                          totalAmount.toDouble());
                                });
                              }

                              return CartItemDesign(
                                model: model,
                                context: context,
                                quanNumber: separateItemQuantityList![index],
                              );
                            },
                            childCount: snapshot.hasData
                                ? snapshot.data!.docs.length
                                : 0,
                          ),
                        );
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell what is the problem without looking at the whole source code.

My guess is that you need to pass the ChangeNotifierProvider instance across routes (basically whenever you do `Navigator.push()`).
Check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69476688/18162964).

Answer (score 1):

When passing **ChangeNotifierProvider** in main

Pass it like this

```
ChangeNotifierProvider(
  create : (context) => CartItemCounter(),
  child : CartScreen (),  // screen where you want to access the Provider

),
```

Comment: I'm still getting the same error. I even restarted the app after making changes  but the error still is there